# SetThreadExecutionState preventing manual sleep

Tags: windows, winapi

On Windows 7, I'm seeing that a call to `SetThreadExecutionState` with the parameter `ES_CONTINUOUS | ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED | ES_AWAYMODE_REQUIRED` is preventing the user from manually putting the system to sleep.

Upon opening the Start menu and selecting 'Sleep,' the display turns off, but my application continues processing. This is evident by the fact that the fan continues at full speed and upon waking the computer, I can see that the operations that were being carried out when the sleep occurred have progressed.

How can I allow the user to manually put their computer to sleep while `SetThreadExecutionState` is in effect?

Comment: Interesting.  According to the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373208%28VS.85%29.aspx) the behavior you describe shouldn't be possible.  It specifically states "The SetThreadExecutionState function cannot be used to prevent the user from putting the computer to sleep."

Comment: I just wrote a small program to test it and it looks like you're right and MSDN is wrong.  The computer **appears** to go to sleep but it does not.  My program kept running and so did everything else.

Comment: It seems the culprit is away mode. Upon further research, away mode seems to totally replace sleep.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Inclusion of the ES_AWAYMODE_REQUIRED option causes this problem.  Quoting from the MSDN article:

> The ES_AWAYMODE_REQUIRED value should be used only when absolutely necessary by media applications that require the system to perform background tasks such as recording television content or streaming media to other devices while the system appears to be sleeping. Applications that do not require critical background processing or that run on portable computers should not enable away mode because it prevents the system from conserving power by entering true sleep.

Comment: Thanks, I think the problem stemmed from the last paragraph of the MSDN page implying that this function doesn't affect user-requested sleep.

Comment: @CollinDauphinee It's a bit stronger than an implication! `The SetThreadExecutionState function cannot be used to prevent the user from putting the computer to sleep` seems pretty unequivocal to me.

Comment: Away mode doesn't prevent the user from putting the computer to sleep. It changes the definition of sleep.